# Is there any way to comment a block in HSPICE?

Tags: hspice

I know "*" comments the line. Is there any way to select a group and comment the whole block in HSPICE?

Answer (score 1):

*Any line starting with * or $ is considered a comment.

*HSPICE also treats things after "`*`" or "$" as comments.
The dollar sign ($) must be used for comments that do not begin in the first
character position on a line
 For example,

```
* RF=1K GAIN SHOULD BE 100
$ MAY THE FORCE BE WITH MY CIRCUIT
VIN 1 0 PL 0 0 5V 5NS $ 10v 50ns
R12 1 0 1MEG $ FEED BACK
.PARAM a=1w$comment a=1, w treated as a space and ignored
.PARAM a=1k$comment a=1e3, k is a scale factor
```

For multi-line comments there is no way but to add $ or * at start of each line.

An .END statement is the last statement in the input netlist file. Text that
follows the .END statement is a comment, and has no effect on the simulation thus the code which is needed to be ignored can also be placed there.

for more details https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi10/cse241a/assign/hspice_sa.pdf

Comment: Yes, I mean is there anything for block comments, for example, /* lines of code */? Otherwise, I have to manually comment each line.

Comment: @Shabnam I don't have HSPICE but I don't think there is such a feature, since the language was not meant to be a programming language like C/C++/etc. That is, you don't spend time writing lines of code with added comments, as much as adding parts, wiring them, running the simulation, with an occasional line commented out. The netlist reflects this.